# Is Material Design, colorPrimary = 500 and colorPrimaryDark must be 700?

Tags: android, material-design

Android Studio 3.5

In my Android app I use **colorPrimary = #6200ee**

Here colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/mcgpalette0_500</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/mcgpalette0_700</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>

    <color name="mcgpalette0_50">#ece0fd</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_100">#d0b3fa</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_200">#b180f7</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_300">#914df3</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_400">#7a26f1</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_500">#6200ee</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_600">#5a00ec</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_700">#5000e9</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_800">#4600e7</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_900">#3400e2</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_A100">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_A200">#ddd6ff</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_A400">#b3a3ff</color>
    <color name="mcgpalette0_A700">#9d8aff</color>
</resources>
```

As you can see the **colorPrimary = mcgpalette0_500**

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">@color/mcgpalette0_500</color>
```

The questions:

1. Is by Material Design the `colorPrimaryDark` must darker and MUST BE `mcgpalette0_700` ?
2. Where I can find generator for Material Design color for Android app?

Comment: https://material.io/resources/color/

Comment: @sonnet what about first question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any color as long as there's enough contrast to read text and see icons placed on your `colorPrimary`/`PrimaryDark`/`Accent`/`Secondary`. By default Android uses these values, but I've seen apps that use dark blue as `colorPrimary` and white as `colorPrimaryDark` and look 100% fine and material.

Some reading: https://www.viget.com/articles/color-contrast/

You can also ask your designer, or here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/, or here: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev to be sure.

There's a couple of web tools that can help you with palette generation:

- https://material.io/resources/color/
- http://juicystudio.com/services/luminositycontrastratio.php
- https://www.materialpalette.com/